# Shell manipulation to get a file from android

Tags: android, shell

I have an Android device from which I need to obtain a log file from. The log file changes every time it's created, so I cannot simply hardcode the name of the file into my script.

What I am thinking, is doing a

```
adb shell "rm /data/trace/*"
```

to delete everything but that file in the folder before I generate the log file. Then maybe I could do

```
adb pull "/data/trace/`adb shell ls /data/trace/`"
```

What I would think this does is execute the ls command it it'll list the only file there. And the rest of this would cause it to pull "/data/trace/file".

However, this doesn't work.

I get the error:

```
' does not existdata/trace/log.8290
```

Does anybody have any tips on how I could do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you against pushing the file up to a webserver? I realize this is very different from pulling the file over ADB, but would it help you?

Comment: Unfortunately I think that would be the equivalent of taking a sledgehammer to deal with a cockroach. I would prefer if I can keep this within a shell-script. Is there no way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that there's an added carriage return '\r' at the end which messes up the syntax.

This is what I did to solve the problem.

```
test_file=`adb shell ls /data/trace/`;
test_file2=`echo $test_file | tr -d '\r'`;
echo "grabbing $test_file2";
adb pull "/data/trace/$test_file2";
```

This strips the carriage return off the file name and makes it possible so I can use it in my adb pull code.

Cheers.